# php source code for calling individual student result

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

The following codes brings out all the individual data in the database. All I need is to display a single individual data session in username and password.

Code used:

```
$sql= "SELECT * FROM $db_tbl WHERE username='" . $_SESSION['myusername'] . "'LIMIT 1";
```

Comment: i think your problem is empty session

Comment: Is not the solution but add a space before `LIMIT 1`

Comment: If `username` is a unique/primary column (and it probably should be) then you don't need `LIMIT 1` - you'll always only get one result.

Comment: Yes, try looking into @vlcekmi3's idea - echo out your session variable, perhaps it is not set.

Comment: agree with @vlcekmi3. check your session. may be it is empty.